# How to remove array item based on key name in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I want to loop through an array with foreach to check if a key name  exists. If the key with that name  does exist, I want to delete the array item which contains it.

I have written following code, which in first condition checks value of array item, and if value of array item is equal to empty string **""**, sets value of that array item to **"-"** (dash character). First condition works well.

```
foreach ($domaindata['administrative'] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == "") {
      $value = "-";
    } 
    else if ($key == "type") {
      unset ($domaindata[$key]);
    }
    echo "<b>$key: </b>$value<br>";
}
```

Now I have added second condition which checks if $key name existst, and if exists remove that array item.

This is **else if** part, but that array item still get outputted.

```
else if ($key == "type") {
      unset ($domaindata[$key]);
    }
```

Array structure is like this:

```
Array
(
    [name] => OWNER NAME
    [address] => OWNER ADDRESS
    [post:number] => OWNER POST OFFICE NUMBER
    [city] => OWNER CITY
    [country] => OWNER COUNTRY CODE
    [telephone] => OWNER TELEPHONE NUMBER
    [fax] => OWNER FAX NUMBER                   // could be empty
    [email] => OWNER EMAIL ADDRESS
    [type] => person
    [user:type] => Fizička osoba
)
```

Comment: Unless you're assigning `$value` on the `$key` again, it won't change. Easy way is doing `$key => &$value` then anytime you write `$value = "-"` it will modify the array in place. Run an `unset` at the end of the foreach to clear the variable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're doing a `foreach` on `$domaindata['administrative']`, not `$domaindata`. So to unset you need to do

```
unset($domaindata['administrative'][$key]);
```

As to why your loop is still showing `type` it's because the unset doesn't affect the loop (you've already made a copy into the loop variables). What I would suggest is you do this before your `foreach` loop

```
if(isset($domaindata['administrative']['type'])) unset($domaindata['administrative']['type']);
```

You can then remove the `elseif` block entirely (which will remove some overhead)

Comment: I think that my condition don't evaluate on **else if ($key == "type")**, because array item is still present,

Comment: @AlanKis I updated my answer to help you deal with that

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating over `$domaindata['administrative']`, not `$domaindata`. Therefore, you should also `unset` element from it:

```
else if ($key == "type") {
  unset ($domaindata['administrative'][$key]);
}
```